# Replace NA row with non-NA value from previous row and certain column

Tags: r, na

I have a matrix, where rows can have NA's for all columns. I want to replace these NA rows with previous row's non-NA value and K-th column.

For example, this matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    2    3
 [5,]   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA
 [8,]    6    7
 [9,]    7    8
[10,]    8    9
```

Must be transformed to this non-NA matrix, where we use 2-th column for replacement:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    2    3
 [5,]    3    3
 [6,]    3    3
 [7,]    3    3
 [8,]    6    7
 [9,]    7    8
[10,]    8    9
```

I wrote a function for this, but using loop:

```
# replaces rows which contains all NAs with non-NA values from previous row and K-th column
na.replace <- function(x, k) {
    cols <- ncol(x)
    for (i in 2:nrow(x)) {
        if (sum(is.na(x[i - 1, ])) == 0 && sum(is.na(x[i, ])) == cols) {
            x[i, ] <- x[i - 1 , k]
        }
    }
    x
}
```

Seems this function works correct, but I want to avoid these loops. Can anyone advice, how I can do this replacement without using loops?

**UPDATE**

[agstudy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838509/agstudy) suggested it's own vectorized non-loop solution:

```
na.replace <- function(mat, k){
  idx       <-  which(rowSums(is.na(mat)) == ncol(mat))
  mat[idx,] <- mat[ifelse(idx > 1, idx-1, 1), k]
  mat
}
```

But this solution returns different and wrong results, comparing to my solution with loops. Why this happens? Theoretically loop and non-loop solutions are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realized my own vectorized version. It returns expected output:

```
na.replace <- function(x, k) {
    isNA <- is.na(x[, k])
    x[isNA, ] <- na.locf(x[, k], na.rm = F)[isNA]
    x
}
```

**UPDATE**

Better solution, without any packages

```
na.lomf <- function(x) {
    if (length(x) > 0L) {
        non.na.idx <- which(!is.na(x))
        if (is.na(x[1L])) {
            non.na.idx <- c(1L, non.na.idx)
        }
        rep.int(x[non.na.idx], diff(c(non.na.idx, length(x) + 1L)))
    }
}

na.lomf(c(NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, NA))
# [1] NA  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  4
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this function. We can replace **NA**'s at any position in a vector.

```
NA.replace <-function(x) {
       i <- cumprod(is.na(x))
       x[!!i] <- x[which.min(i)]
        if (length(x) > 0L) {
            non.na.idx <- which(!is.na(x))
            if (is.na(x[1L])) {
                non.na.idx <- c(1L, non.na.idx)
            }
            rep.int(x[non.na.idx], diff(c(non.na.idx, length(x) + 1L)))
        }  
}

NA.replace(c(NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, NA))

# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT : I completely change the first solution based in na.locf is

Here a new **vectorized** solution:

```
idx <- which(rowSums(is.na(mat)) == ncol(mat))
mat[idx,1:2]= mat[ifelse(idx>1,idx-1,1),2]

     X..1. X..2.
[1,]     NA    NA
[2,]     NA    NA
[3,]      1     2
[4,]      2     3
[5,]      3     3
[6,]      4     5
[7,]      5     5
[8,]      6     7
[9,]      7     8
[10,]     8     9
```

You can wrap this in a function :

```
function(mat,k){
  idx       <-  which(rowSums(is.na(mat)) == ncol(mat))
  mat[idx,] <- mat[ifelse(idx>1,idx-1,1),k]
}
```

Comment: I know about na.locf, but this function is not suitable for my problem. It replaces NAs with previous non-NAs from the same column. Your output matrix is wrong: row 5 must have (3, 3) values and row 7 - (5, 5) values.

Comment: I found that, if at least 2 consecutive rows have NAs, for example 6-th and 7-th rows then your solution substitutes only 6-th row but not 7-th row. I updated my example in topic with better variant.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `na.locf` function in a loop that simply uses the next column to generate a vector of replacement values. However, this may not be very efficient if your matrix is large.

```
library(zoo)

m <- cbind(
    c(NA, NA, 1, 2, NA, 4, NA, 6, 7, 8),
    c(NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 7, 8, 9)
)

m[, ncol(m)] <- na.locf(m[, ncol(m)], na.rm=FALSE)

for (i in seq(ncol(m)-1, 1)) {
    replacement_values = na.locf(m[, i+1], na.rm=FALSE)
    m[is.na(m[, i]), i] <- replacement_values[is.na(m[, i])]    
}
```

Comment: At first, I didn't see that imputation was taking place in the last column too. How do you intend for that to take place? Is the last column a regular `na.locf`, or are the values at `[5,2]` and `[7,2]` taken from the previous column in the same row?

Comment: Yes, for the last column result is the same like as na.locf, because we replace last column's NA values with previous non-NA values from the same last column. This is just special case.