# How to replace NA with latest value in unbalanced panel?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, panel-data

I would like to replace NA with previous value in an unbalanced panel data (long format). Before replace, the data would look like

```
Firm    Date    Var_1       
AAA 19990430    NA      
AAA 19990531    10      
AAA 19990630    NA      
AAA 19990731    NA      
AAA 19990831    12      
AAA 19990930    NA      
BBB 20040331    NA      
BBB 20040430    NA      
BBB 20040531    8       
BBB 20040630    NA      
BBB 20040731    NA      
BBB 20040831    12      
BBB 20040930    NA
```

After, it will look like:

```
Firm    Date    Var_1       
AAA 19990430    NA      
AAA 19990531    10      
AAA 19990630    10      
AAA 19990731    10      
AAA 19990831    12      
AAA 19990930    12      
BBB 20040331    NA      
BBB 20040430    NA      
BBB 20040531    8       
BBB 20040630    8       
BBB 20040731    8       
BBB 20040831    12      
BBB 20040930    12
```

The point is the two NAs at the beginning of Firm BBB shall not be replaced by the numbers from firm AAA.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are so many duplicates for this. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/using-dplyr-window-functions-to-make-trailing-values-fill-in-na-values), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573801/replace-na-row-with-non-na-value-from-previous-row-and-certain-column) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `zoo` and the function `na.locf()`.

Let's say your data.frame above is called `df`.

```
df$Firm<-factor(df$Firm)
library(zoo)

#turn your df into a zoo object
df.zoo<-zoo(df)

#split on "Firm" and put df into a list.
df.list<-split(df.zoo,f=df.zoo$Firm)

#apply na.locf function to both Firms
df.list$`AAA`<-na.locf(df.list$`AAA`, na.rm=F)
df.list$`BBB`<-na.locf(df.list$`BBB`, na.rm=F)

#paste your df back together
rbind(
data.frame(na.locf(df.list$`AAA`, na.rm=F)),
data.frame(na.locf(df.list$`BBB`, na.rm=F))
)
```

You will get

```
   Firm     Date Var_1
1   AAA 19990430  <NA>
2   AAA 19990531    10
3   AAA 19990630    10
4   AAA 19990731    10
5   AAA 19990831    12
6   AAA 19990930    12
7   BBB 20040331  <NA>
8   BBB 20040430  <NA>
9   BBB 20040531     8
10  BBB 20040630     8
11  BBB 20040731     8
12  BBB 20040831    12
13  BBB 20040930    12
```