# Filling missing values in R matrix using previous value in the same row

Tags: r, matrix, missing-data, fillna

Consider the following example

```
before = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, 1), ncol = 3)
after = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1), ncol = 3)
```

The matrix before is the kind of matrix I always deal with in terms of position of missing values, whereas the matrix after is the one I need to get to repeatedly.
Is there any efficient routine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `na.locf()` from `{zoo}` row-wisely (`MARGIN = 1L`):

```r
> before = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, 1), ncol = 3)
> after = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1), ncol = 3)
> (before2 = t(apply(before, 1L, zoo::na.locf)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    4    4
[3,]    3    5    1
> identical(before2, after)
[1] TRUE
```

Read the documentation, there are plenty of options implemented.
Or write your own function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749637/20002111).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
before[is.na(before)] <- before[which(is.na(before))-nrow(before)]
```

In case you have more than one NA per row, you may use a loop:

```
while(any(is.na(before))){
  before[is.na(before)] <- before[which(is.na(before))-nrow(before)]
}

> identical(before,after)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `replace` with `tail` of length 1 of the non-NAs.

```
> t(apply(before, 1, \(x) replace(x, is.na(x), tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    4    4
[3,]    3    5    1
```